# Can anyone assist with the sql to extract data from this xml please?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this XML in a DB column called `xml_data` in a table called `awfmsvalues`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<m>
    <agladdress change_type="2" row_id="31c17cbd-cc84-4cbf-afd4-42ca7c1cd351" last_update="2024-02-23      09:51:52">
        <key>
            <c col="client">EA</c>
            <c col="attribute_id">A4</c>
            <c col="dim_value">TEST123</c>
            <c col="address_type">3</c>
            <c col="sequence_no">1</c>
        </key>
        <c old="" col="e_mail">test@email.co.uk</c>
    </agladdress>
    <acuheader change_type="0" row_id="3ac032da-683e-44bc-9ab6-6f58a70108df" last_update="2024-02-23 09:50:23">
        <key>
            <c col="client">EA</c>
            <c col="apar_id">TEST123</c>
        </key>
    </acuheader>
</m>
```

I want to get the value of `dim_value` in a basic view for starters.

This is what I have tried;

```sql
select 
    x.xml_data.value('(/m/agladdress/key/dim_value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as shredded_dim
from
    (select cast(xml_data as xml) as xml_data from awfmsvalues where client = 'EA')x
```

It's just returning a failed to create result error though.

Have I even got the syntax right?

Comment: You have to remove the prolog part `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` by a REPLACE because sql server cannot switch encodings

Comment: I can't replicate your error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oyyBm93U) I just get a `NULL` value (which is expected, as there's no node called `dim_value`).

Comment: `Have I even got the syntax right?` - yes, you have. It's not going to return you the value you want because you are querying something else, but the syntax is correct. Please post the actual error message.

Comment: does the xml as text work? itll help us if you try the query without the xml parsing

Comment: @siggemannen There is no need to remove it because it's utf-16. There would be if it was something else.

Comment: Well, I can't cast it from varchar so maybe that's the issue. Real error message would be helpful

Comment: @siggemannen no it's not. The column's type is `xml`, not a text type. If the cast was impossible `cast(xml_data as xml)` would throw

Comment: @siggemannen Try casting from `nvarchar`.

Comment: `dim_value` is neither an element nor an attribute name. It's the *value* of the `col` attribute. This schema isn't very well thought out. Without an XML schema nothing prevents using `client` or `dim_value` as actual elements. As it is, the XPATH should search for the element who's `col` attribute is equal to `dim_value` and extract the contents.

Comment: Perhaps `(/m/agladdress/key/c[@col="dim_value"])[1]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, he does get an error, so maybe that's the original error but it gets wrapped into something else on the way

Answer (score 1):

`dim_value` is neither an element nor an attribute name. It's the *value* of the `col` attribute. This schema isn't very well thought out. Without an XML schema nothing prevents using `client` or `dim_value` as actual elements.

As it is, the XPATH should search for the element who's `col` attribute is equal to `dim_value` and extract the contents. This can be done with :

```
/m/agladdress/key/c[@col="dim_value"]
```

There's no guarantee this will return a single value though, so the first result should be selected:

```
(/m/agladdress/key/c[@col="dim_value"])[1]
```

The final query should be :

```
select 
    x.xml_data.value('(/m/agladdress/key/c[@col="dim_value"])[1]',
                     'VARCHAR(20)') as shredded_dim
from
    (select cast(xml_data as xml) as xml_data 
     from awfmsvalues 
     where client = 'EA') x
```

As [this fiddle shows](https://dbfiddle.uk/FooAhfId), the result will be :

```
TEST123
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this when running the above?

XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: @IanH what's the actual type of the `xml_data` field? It should be `nvarchar`. If not, the XML is lying about its encoding. That's a table design bug. You'd have to remove prolog in that case. Or you should change the field type to `xml` to *prevent* storage of incorrect data n the first place, along with the need to cast. Once you change to `xml` you can create [XML indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) which make querying a *LOT* faster

Comment: Argh, it's varchar!

Comment: I assume then I will have to go down the charindex route instead

Comment: @IanH You can do `cast(cast(xml_data as nvarchar(max)) as xml)`, but the data in that column is *already damaged* unless every single character is in the first 127 ASCII range.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos told you :)

Answer (score 0):

This works;

```
select 
x.xml_data.value('(/m/agladdress/key/c[@col="dim_value"])[1]',
'VARCHAR(20)') as shredded_dim
from
(select cast(replace(xml_data,'utf-16','utf-8')as xml) as xml_data 
 from awfmsvalues 
 where client = 'EA') x
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It replaces one lie about the XML encoding with another, and it will get back to you as soon as you have a character there that is not from the first 127 ASCII characters. UTF-8 is not latin1 that you most likely have in that column. Please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**